# how use with image in Android?

Tags: android

I have a map divided by areas and I want when the user clicks on a specific area will tour places where,
My question is how do this, each area will have event onclick then?
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: do you have the image of map ?

Answer (score 0):

nWhat maps are you using for it? Is it `Google` maps? If it is `Google map` (or any other popular map engine) you can set `onMapClickListener` on that map, and get coordinates of that click, the check to what area this coordinates belongs to.

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point)
            {
            //check to what area that point belongs to, and show Popup With that place  

            }

        });
```

Anyway, to show specific image in some custom area you can use `PopupWindow`, here is the answer how to deal with it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

P.s. In case of using google maps, it is better to use `Markers` to show area photos, see official docs for it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker

Answer (score 0):

See the coding of a keyboard that fetch event for specific coordinate.